# Can I move the scrollbar, and make it always visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

[image]
[image]

When I expand one of my nodes, and the data goes down below the bottom of the window, the scrollbar appears and makes the top bar squish up a bit. Is there any way I can make the scrollbar only show in the bottom white area. Also, can I make it always show even if it's not needed, so it doesn't appear and disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the white area a fixed height and set `overflow` to either `auto` or `scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a css 'min-height' on an element that can be larger than the window;  `body { min-height: 101%; }` might do it.